# Using SkipJack in IOS based application

Tags: ios

I am new to IOS development and will be porting a legacy desktop system to IPad Application. The legacy system uses SkipJACK as a payment gateway. Am i allowed to use this in IOS. I have searched alot on the internet but have not been able to find anything.

Has anyone used SkipJACK in IOS ?

Kind Regards

Comment: it depends, are the user buying digital good then no, Apple will allow the use of payment system as long as it is for physical goods. So buying for example an e-book you will need to use Apple InApp purchase, if you are selling a really copy of book to be send to the user then you need to provide your own payment provider.

Comment: I would be using this to allow the user to view their lawyer records ? Would this be classed as a Digital or Physical good ?

Comment: @rckoenes What about the above ?

Comment: It would definitely be digitals, since there are no goods send to the user and you app will allow the viewing of such documents. But If you are still unsure you can always ask Apples review board.